# c# - @foreach (var item in Model)

Tags: c#, database, model-view-controller, model

***This is different from NullReferanceException question, because we are dealing with a project that has been separated by concerns, making it different in some ways - as previous answers were dealing with one project, we are working with 3 different projects and namespaces.***

I keep getting this:

```
Line 41:         <th></th>
Line 42:     </tr>
Line 43:     @foreach (var item in Model)
Line 44:     {
Line 45:         <tr>
```

**Description**: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details**: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

This is my code:

**DVD.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace DVDStore.Data.Models
{

    public class DVD
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        //public byte[] Picture { get; set; }
        // Foreign Key
        public virtual Ratings RatingsID { get; set; }
        // Foreign Key
        public virtual Genres GenresID { get; set; }
        // Foreign Key
        public virtual SalesInfo SalesInfoID { get; set; }
        //Foreign Key
        public virtual ICollection<Actor> Actors { get; set; }
    }


    public class MovieDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<DVD> DVDs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using DVDStore.Access.Methods;

namespace DVDStore.WEB.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {

        public ActionResult Index()
        {

        FindAllDVDs findDVDs = new FindAllDVDs();

            return View(findDVDs);
        }
    }
```

**Access**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using DVDStore.Data.Models;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace DVDStore.Access.Methods
{
    public class FindAllDVDs
    {
        //List<FindAllDVDs> dVDs = new List<FindAllDVDs>();

        private DVDStoreContext db = new DVDStoreContext();

        public dynamic ViewBag { get; }

        public void FindAllDVD(string DVDTitles, string searchString)
        {
            var FindDVDS = new List<string>();

            var DVDQuery = from d in db.DVD
                           orderby d.Title
                           select d.Title;

            FindDVDS.AddRange(DVDQuery.Distinct());
            ViewBag.DVDTitles = new SelectList(FindDVDS);

            var dvds = from dvd in db.DVD
                       select dvd;

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchString))
            {
                dvds = dvds.Where(s => s.Title.Contains(searchString));
            }
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(DVDTitles))
            {
                dvds = dvds.Where(x => x.Title == DVDTitles);

            }

        }

    }

    }
```

and finally the **index.schtml** where I'm getting the problem

***Everything compiles w/ 0 errors btw***

```
@*@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}*@

@model IEnumerable<DVDStore.Data.Models.DVD>


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p></p>

@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")


@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "DVD", FormMethod.Get))
{
    <p>
        Title: @Html.TextBox("SearchString") <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
    </p>
}
}
 </p>

<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Price)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
            </td>

        </tr>
    }

</table>

 </table>
```

Comment: Of course its a duplicate - it makes no difference if multiple projects of namespaces. The `Model` in `@foreach (var item in Model)` is `null`. And the code in your `public ActionResult Index()` method make no sense. All you have done is initialize an instance of your class. You have not even called your `FindAllDVD()` method, which does not return anything any way.

Comment: Alex, there is one single cause of this exception: a value that you are trying to use is null. Therefore every NullReferenceException question is a duplicate. The question yours duplicates explains all the ways things can be null and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `FindAllDVD` method so that it has:

```
return dvds;
```

as its last line. This will likely mean changing the signature to:

```
public IEnumerable<DVD> FindAllDVD(string DVDTitles, string searchString)
```

Then, rather than passing `findDVDs` to the view, you need to pass the **result** of `findDVDs.FindAllDVD` instead:

```
FindAllDVDs findDVDs = new FindAllDVDs();
return View(findDVDs.FindAllDVD("", ""));
```

*This way your `Model` will be using the set of `DVDs` rather than the single instance of the `FindAllDVDs` class like it is now.*

Answer (score 1):

Your view is expecting a collection of `DVD` type model.

```
@model IEnumerable<DVDStore.Data.Models.DVD>
```

However, in your Controller, you are passing an instance of `FindAllDVDs`.

```
        FindAllDVDs findDVDs = new FindAllDVDs();
        return View(findDVDs);
```

You should pass a List of `DVD` objects.

Update:

The quickest way would be to return the list of DVD objects from your method.

```
public IEnumerable<DVDStore.Data.Models.DVD> FindAllDVD(string DVDTitles, string searchString)
```

and return the list of Dvds.

Then in your controller, you can do this:

```
FindAllDVDs findDVDs = new FindAllDVDs();
IEnumerable<Dvd> dvds = findDVDs.FindAllDVD(<DVDTitles>, <searchString>);
return View(dvds);
```

However, I would not recommend that approach. You don't want to use your data model as your view model. I would rather create a separate DVD class as model for the View, and then map the Data model to this View Model.

Comment: how would i pass that?

Comment: The quickest way would be to return the list of DVD objects from your method.  <br/>

`public IEnumerable<DVDStore.Data.Models.DVD> FindAllDVD(string DVDTitles, string searchString)`  <br/>
and return the list Dvds.

Then in your controller, you can do this:  <br/>

`FindAllDVDs findDVDs = new FindAllDVDs();`  <br/>
 `IEnumerable<Dvd> dvds = findDVDs.FindAllDVD(<DVDTitles>, <searchString>);`  <br/>
 `return View(dvds);`  <br/>
However, I would not recommend that approach. I would rather create a separate DVD class as model for the View, and then map the Data model to this View Model.

Comment: sorry, my comment is a bit messy, still struggling with this comment formatting. I updated my answer with what I described.

Answer (score 1):

Inside of `FindAllDVDs` you have `the List<FindAllDVDs> dVDs = new List<FindAllDVDs>();` that is set inside the constructor.

You can just call the constructor as you just did (remember to uncomment the dvds property, like this:

```
public List<FindAllDVDs> dVDs = new List<FindAllDVDs>();
```

and set the values inside the constructor, like this:

```
dVDs = dvds;
```

Maybe you'll need to do some cast, like this:

```
dVDs = dvds.toList();
```

, and pass the value that is inside the `FindAllDVDs`, like this:

```
FindAllDVDs findDVDs = new FindAllDVDs("","");

return View(findDVDs.dvds);
```

Comment: it doesn't seem to be recognizing the dvds - you mean uncomment the dVDs correct?

Comment: I made a more detailed description now, I meam uncomment the property at the top of `FindAllDVDs` and use that to get the value for the controller.